# I have got time in the format of day:hh:mm:ss in the datatype of string. how can i convert this in a single format of days?

Tags: java, logic

I am trying to display duration on to a pie chart I have time in the format of days:hh:mm: ss how can I convert this into no of day's format so that I can display that on the pie chart.

thanks in advance

P.S: the days:hh:mm:ss is in the datatype of String

Comment: For the number of hours and minutes, you are going to represent them with floating-point or simply you reject them?

Comment: There is probably some solution based on already existing classes for date/time manipulation. However in this case you can also split the string by a colon, convert strings to numbers and then manually combine them into an answer.

Comment: Post an example, please. A full one...